How can I fix an AppArmor policy that prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient in my Ubuntu ARM server?
I have a big problem here and it's been 16 days since I asked it on Stackoverflow and I got no answer. So, here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79176447/how-can-i-fix-an-apparmor-policy-prevents-this-sender-from-sending-this-message . I've done lots and lots of research and I can't solve it. That's why I'm asking you to help me... So, as you can see when I run chromium --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf='/home/johndoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-en.pdf' 'https://files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326.html' && mv '/home/johndoe/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-en. pdf' '/var/www/files.domain.com/docs/' && echo 'files.transladocs.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-en.pdf' directly in my ARM server's SSH it displays its errors and then converts it to PDF but when I try to do it directly in my site it doesn't work at all. Please consult the question to see all the details.
Here's the errors that it gave me:
[17035:17192:1111/053835.545588:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.71" (uid=1000 pid=17035 comm="/snap/chromium/2992/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)                                       [17035:17192:1111/053835.604277:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ListActivatableNames: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.73" (uid=1000 pid=17035 comm="/snap/chromium/2992/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrom" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="ListActivatableNames" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)                                       754773 bytes written to file /home/john/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf                                         files.domain.com/docs/407163caf78c6deedcb8bf732e7e1326-fr.pdf   
So, what do I have to do to fix this definitively please? All will help me a lot... I'm totally blocked here...

The simplest solution may be to disable AppArmor. Is the machine connected to the public internet? If not, the risk of consequence is low.

@matigo Yes, it's connected to the Internet. It's a server ARM online that i bought on netcup.de

@matigo How can I disable AppArmor on my Ubuntu ARM server?

You can temporarily stop AppArmor like this: sudo systemctl stop apparmor. It runs as a service, so it will restart at the next boot.
